# xparse optional parameter IfValueT true without parameter

Tags: xparse

I created a custom commadn with one mandatory and 4 optional parameters with

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \quote { m o o o o} {% 
\glqq\textit{#1}\grqq\
\IfValueT {#2 \OR #3 \OR #4 \OR #5} {(}%
\IfValueT {#2}{p. #2}%
\IfValueT {#3}{, ll. #3}%
\IfValueT {#4}{, \textsc{#4}}%
\IfValueT {#5}{, #5}%
\IfValueT {#2 \OR #3 \OR #4 \OR #5} {)}%
}
```

But using

```
\quote{something}
```

returns

[image: result]

What am i doing wrong, and yes I know the code has some other flaws cosidering it should be a quote.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've no idea where you are getting `\OR` from but it's clear that `#2 \OR #3 \OR #4 \OR #5` is never going to be exactly equal to `-NoValue-` (a marker for _exactly one_ optional argument being absent).

Comment: So I need to nest all of them as in `\IfValueT {#2}{\IfValueT {#3}{\IfValueT {#4}{\IfValueT {#5}{(}}}}`?

Comment: First of all you should never use `\DeclareDocumentCommand` if you don't know what you're doing (`\quote` is already defined in LaTeX). Second, a command with four optional arguments will be a nightmare for users.

Comment: apart from the syntax not being correct what do you want `\IfValueT {#2 \OR #3 \OR #4 \OR #5} {(}%` to do? you only need to test `#2`  as it is not possible `#3` to be supplied but not `#2` (which is why having consecutive optional arguments is almost never a good choice)

Comment: Now, in Linux `apt-get`, a command using {mooo} would have Super Cow powers.

Comment: Thank you i have fixed it, and no this is not really my code, i just thought of this being a easy to understand example.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `\OR` for multiple tests of `\IfValueTF`. You could implement one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\QUOTE}{moooo}
 {
  \glqq\textit{#1}\grqq
  \berserker_quote_if_novalue:nnnnF { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { ~( }
  \IfValueT{#2}{p.~#2}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{,~ll.~#3}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{,~\textsc{#4}}%
  \IfValueT{#5}{,~#5}%
  \berserker_quote_if_novalue:nnnnF { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { ) }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \berserker_quote_if_novalue:nnnn { TF,T,F,p }
 {
  \bool_lazy_all:nTF
   {
    {\tl_if_novalue_p:n { #1 }}
    {\tl_if_novalue_p:n { #2 }}
    {\tl_if_novalue_p:n { #3 }}
    {\tl_if_novalue_p:n { #4 }}
   }
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\QUOTE{I said}

\QUOTE{I said}[a]

\QUOTE{I said}[a][b]

\QUOTE{I said}[a][b][c]

\QUOTE{I said}[a][b][c][d]

\end{document}
```

[image]

***Caveat*** This doesn't work with the present release of `expl3`, due to a definition that unfortunately slipped out. A fix should be on its way.

A better way to go would be with a key-value syntax. Use more meaningful names, as it's not really clear what the arguments are supposed to contain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\QUOTE}{mo}
 {
  \glqq\textit{#1}\grqq
  \group_begin:
  \IfValueT{#2}{ ~( \berserker_quote_options:n { #2 } ) }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { berserker/quote }
 {
  p .tl_set:N = \l__berserker_quote_page_tl,
  l .tl_set:N = \l__berserker_quote_lines_tl,
  n .tl_set:N = \l__berserker_quote_note_tl,
  c .tl_set:N = \l__berserker_quote_comment_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \berserker_quote_options:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { berserker/quote } { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__berserker_quote_page_tl {p.~\l__berserker_quote_page_tl}
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__berserker_quote_lines_tl {,~ll.~\l__berserker_quote_lines_tl}
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__berserker_quote_note_tl {,~\textsc{\l__berserker_quote_note_tl}}
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__berserker_quote_comment_tl {,~\l__berserker_quote_comment_tl}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\QUOTE{I said}

\QUOTE{I said}[p=a]

\QUOTE{I said}[p=a,l=b]

\QUOTE{I said}[p=a,l=b,n=c]

\QUOTE{I said}[p=a,l=b,n=c,c=d]

\end{document}
```